# How to monitor other nodes to get RSSI?

Tags: linux, command-line, networking, wifi

I need to measure RSSI between two peers of nodes in same network.
If I have these two information:

1. SSID for their network.
2. IP for the target node to get the RSSI regarding it.

So I found this command: `iwspy` but it seems that not found in the kernel and I see this [link](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=51e779f0daa5c712439d37b907d58543e4fcf12a) 
that talk about:

> We removed iwspy support a very long time ago because it is useless, but forgot to stop claiming to support it. Apparently, nobody cares, but remove it nonetheless.

Comment: What type of network ? If it is IBSS, Mesh or your interface is in access point mode, then `iw dev wlan0 station dump` will list them and their RSSI. And yes, `iwspy`, `iwconfig`, `iwlist` `iwpriv` sucks and are deprecated.

Comment: actually i used WIFI DIRECT network where the owner node will act as access point and others as client.
So what are suitable commands in my case ???

Answer (score 2):

If your interface is in IBSS, Mesh point, or AP/P2P Group Owner mode, then you can dump the stations's MAC and their signal level as perceived by your network card with `iw dev wlan0 station dump`.

As for fetching the MAC from the IP address, a suggestion would be to use the ARP table with `ip neigh`. Note that you may have to ping the IP address to populate the ARP table.

So, to fetch the RSSI for a node claiming address A, it could be:

```
MAC="$(ip neigh show to A dev wlan0 | cut -f 3 -d ' ')"
if [ -n "$MAC" ]; then
    iw dev wlan0 station get "$MAC" | sed -nre "s@\s*signal:\s*@@p"
else
    # no ARP entry. Ping the address and retry.
fi
```

If, however, your interface is not on this type (e.g. Non-AP sta), then you will have to fiddle with monitor mode, and you have no reliable way to get a MAC address from an IP address (hint: if the station is routing, then it will use the IP of the sender, not his own).

---

As said before, `iwconfig/iwspy/iwlist/iwpriv` are deprecated and sucks. they use a kernel API (wireless extensions) which is deprecated and is only implemented for retrocompatibility purpose, and only if enabled in the kernel configuration. Many part of it are thereby faked or lacks many features, including Wi-Fi direct. If you are using Wi-Fi direct, then you are already using the modern nl80211 kernel API, and you should forget about the wext API and `iwconfig/iwspy`.

And yes, you need the MAC address of the node. Wi-Fi operates at layer 1 and 2 on the OSI model and does not care about the upper layer. An IP and a MAC address serves different purpose and are not the same thing.

Comment: do i need Mac instead of IP????

and i didn't get every thing here !!!

we can't use iwspy, iwconfig any more ?

Comment: also i used android here

Comment: @Hanna: Updated the answer. Using Android will not change the kernel API, so if `iw` is not available, you will have to compile it or create a program which does the same thing using the `nl80211` API.

Comment: if i have these information as above :

the owner IP as following :
public String getHostAddress () 

Returns the numeric representation of this IP address (such as "127.0.0.1").

Comment: and SSID as follow 

public String getNetworkName ()
Get the network name (SSID) of the group. Legacy Wi-Fi clients will discover the p2p group using the network name.

Comment: it seems that you write code in C ?? not command lines ?

Comment: if the Mac address of the owner is "locally administered " 

The device MAC address uniquely identifies a Wi-Fi p2p device

Comment: from "iw" document i don't find commands to find RSSI given Mac address ?? 
http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Documentation/iw